# Why is the empirical measure $L_n=\frac1 n \sum_{k=1}^n\delta_{X_k}$ a random variable with values in $\mathscr M_1(\{0,1\})$?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

According to the following example,

[image]

the empirical measure $L_n=\frac1 n\sum_{k=1}^n\delta_{X_k}$ is defined as  a  random variable with values in $\mathscr M_1(\{0,1\})$

**1) How can that be? Why is it a random variable and at the same time a measure? And most importantly how can the image be $\mathscr M_1(\{0,1\})$**? As far as I know a measure is a real-valued function. But in the example they say it takes values in $\mathscr M_1({0,1})$.

My book defines:

[image]

so $\mathscr M_1(\{0,1\})$ should be the space of Borel-measures over $S=\{0,1\}$.And the Borel sigma algebra  should be just $\mathscr B(S)=\{ \{0 \},\{ 1\},\{0,1 \},\emptyset\}$

**2)Additionally to get the expressions for $L_n$ and $\nu_n$ in the Bernoulli case, I tried doing this:**

For $\nu_n$ :

Let $A \subseteq \mathscr Y$ be a Borel set

By definition of distribution of a random variable

$\nu_n$ is the distribution of $L_n$ so $\nu_n(A)=\mathbb P(L_n\in A)$

$\mu_n$ is the distribution of $\frac{S_n}{n}$ so $\mu_n(A)=\mathbb P(\frac{S_n}{n}\in A)$

$\mu\circ f^{-1}(A)=\mu( f^{-1}(A))=\mathbb P(\frac{S_n}{n}\in f^{-1}(A))$

$=\mathbb P(f(\frac{S_n}{n})\in A)=\mathbb P(\frac{S_n}{n}\delta_1+(1-\frac{S_n}{n})\delta_0\in A)=$
$\mathbb P(L_n \in A)=\nu_n(A)$

**But I am not sure if the following step was correct:**

$\mathbb P(\frac{S_n}{n}\in f^{-1}(A))=\mathbb P(f(\frac{S_n}{n})\in A)$

because if I remember correctly only the following is true $f(f^{-1})(A)\subseteq A$ for a generic f.

**If it was correct, why? and is there a name for the property in such step? If not, how do I prove it then? And how do I get the expression for $L_n$?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1)** Recall that an $\mathcal{S}$-valued random variable, where $\mathcal{S}$ is a measurable space, is simply a measurable function from the ambient probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbf{P})$ to $\mathcal{S}$.

In OP's case, $L_n$ takes two inputs, a sample $\omega \in \Omega$ and a Borel subset $B$ of $\{0,1\}$, and gives the value

$$ L_n(\omega, B) = \frac{S_n(\omega)}{n} \delta_1(B) + \left(1 - \frac{S_n(\omega)}{n}\right) \delta_0(B). $$

By partially evaluating $L_n$ at each given $\omega$ but leaving $B$ free, we can regard $L_n$ as a function

\begin{align*}
L_n(\omega)
&= \left[ B \mapsto \frac{S_n(\omega)}{n} \delta_1(B) + \left(1 - \frac{S_n(\omega)}{n}\right) \delta_0(B) \right] \\
&= \frac{S_n(\omega)}{n} \delta_1 + \left(1 - \frac{S_n(\omega)}{n}\right) \delta_0.
\end{align*}

Each of these values is a probability measure on $\{0, 1\}$, and so, $L_n$ is an $\mathscr{M}_1(\{0,1\})$-valued random variable, provided it is measurable. This requires us to endow $\mathscr{M}_1(\{0,1\})$ with a $\sigma$-algebra so that it becomes a measurable space. This $\sigma$-algebra is usually chosen as the smallest one for which the map

$$ I_B : \mathscr{M}_1(\{0,1\}) \to \mathbb{R}, \qquad I_B(\mu) = \mu(B) $$

is measurable for each Borel subset $B$ of $\{0, 1\}$. An immediate consequence of this definition is that the followings are equivalent for a function $Y : \Omega \to \mathscr{M}_1(\{0,1\})$:

- $Y$ is measurable (hence an $\mathscr{M}_1(\{0,1\})$-valued random variable);
- $ I_B \circ Y : \Omega \to \mathbb{R} $ is measurable (hence a real-valued random variable) for each Borel subset $B$ of $\{ 0, 1\}$.

However, in OP's case,

$$ I_B \circ L_n = \frac{S_n}{n} \mathbf{1}_{\{1 \in B\}} + \left(1 - \frac{S_n}{n}\right) \mathbf{1}_{\{0 \in B\}} $$

is a real-valued random variable since $S_n$ is. Therefore $L_n$ is also an ($\mathscr{M}_1(\{0,1\})$-valued) random variable.

**2)**
The logical relation $$ x\in f^{-1}(A) \qquad\iff\qquad f(x)\in A $$ holds for any function $f:X\to Y$, $x \in X$, and $A \subseteq Y$. This is because the right-hand side is the very *defining property* for the set $f^{-1}(A)$: $$f^{-1}(A) := \{x \in X : f(x) \in A\}$$

As for determining the law of $L_n$, note that $L_n$ can only take any of the values

$$ \text{Ber}(\tfrac{k}{n}) = \tfrac{k}{n}\delta_1 + \tfrac{n-k}{n}\delta_0, \qquad k=0,1,\ldots,n. $$

Moreover, for each $k = 0, 1, \ldots, n$, the probability of the event $\{L_n = \text{Ber}(\tfrac{k}{n})\}$ is computed by

$$ \nu_n(\{\text{Ber}(\tfrac{k}{n})\})
= \mathbf{P}(L_n = \text{Ber}(\tfrac{k}{n}))
= \mathbf{P}(S_n=k)
= \binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}.$$

This tells that $\nu_n$ is a discrete measure given by

$$ \nu_n
= \sum_{k=0}^{n} \mathbf{P}(L_n = \text{Ber}(\tfrac{k}{n})) \delta_{\text{Ber}(k/n)}
= \sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k} p^k (1-p)^{n-k} \delta_{\text{Ber}(k/n)}. $$

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I still don't see how $L_n (\omega)$ is a probability measure on $\{0,1\}$. I mean why on $\{0,1\}$?  The only values the deltas $\delta_0$ and $\delta_1$ take are $0 $ or 1, so $Ln(\omega)$ can only be one of this values: $0,1,\frac{S_n(\omega)}{n} \delta_1,  1 - \frac{S_n(\omega)}{n}\delta_0.$ so not only $0$ and 1. For $L_n$ to be $\{0,1\}$-valued, I need the image to be only $\{0,1\}$

Comment: Another thing, you said that "By partially evaluating $L_n$ at each given $\omega$ but leaving $B$ free we can regard $L_n$ as a function.Each of these values is a probability measure on $\{0, 1\}$ and so, $L_n$ is an $\mathscr{M}_1(\{0,1\})$-valued random variable, provided it is measurable".  But to see $L_n$ as a rndom variable, shouldn't I do the opposite than what we do to see it as a measure? That is, fix B, and leave $\omega$ free?. Could you elaborate on the equivalence of the definition you gave with that in the bullet points? I'm unfamiliar with itt. Does this definition have a name?

Comment: Regarding 2), my question was actually (but don't erase what you did) how to go from   the general definition $L_n=\frac1 n\sum_{k=1}^n\delta_{X_k}$ to the particular one for the example case: $$ L_n(\omega, B) = \frac{S_n(\omega)}{n} \delta_1(B) + \left(1 - \frac{S_n(\omega)}{n}\right) \delta_0(B). $$

Comment: It seems to me that you are not familiar with the notion of measure and/or are confusing the notion of measure with that of random variable. I know that it is a bit hard to chew in the first place, but you may experiment with some elementary example to grasp some idea as to how it works. For example, consider the scenario in which $n=5$ and $X_1(\omega)=1$, $X_2(\omega)=0$, $X_3(\omega)=0$, $X_4(\omega)=1$, $X_5(\omega)=1$. For this particular $\omega$, $$L_5(\omega)=\frac{1}{5}(\delta_1+\delta_0+\delta_0+\delta_1+\delta_1)=\frac{3}{5}\delta_1+\frac{2}{5}\delta_0$$

Comment: *(continuing from the previous comment)* This $L_5(\omega)$ is a probability measure on $\{0,1\}$, or equivalently $L_5(\omega)\in\mathcal{M}_1(\{0,1\})$, meaning that for each $B$ in $\mathcal{B}(\{0,1\})=\{\varnothing,\{0\},\{1\},\{0,1\}\}$, we get $$L_5(\omega,B)=\frac{3}{5}\delta_1(B)+\frac{2}{5}\delta_0(B)=\frac{3}{5}\mathbf{1}_{\{1\in B\}}+\frac{2}{5}\mathbf{1}_{\{0\in B\}}.$$

Comment: Finally, the term 'random variable' in this answer is not restricted to '$\mathbb{R}$-valued measurable function $\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$', but rather it encompasses any type of random objects taking values in a given measurable space. Random variables with widely used value types often get a special name, such as 'random vector = vector-valued random variable', 'random measure = measure-valued random variable', etc. In this regard, $L_n$ is a **random measure**. (That's right, a distribution/probability law/probability distribution itself can be random!)

Comment: Part of the confusion was indeed that my definition of random variable regarded it as real-valued. In my probability course, we had only random varibles and random vectors, the former was defined as real valued and the later as $\mathbb R^n$-valued. I did not suspected this definition wasn't general as all common distributions  are of those two types (normal, esp, bernoulli, binomial, etc)

Comment: I still have a doubt . Let It is now clear that $L_n(\omega)$is a probability mesure over some set  for fixed $\omega$, but why precisely over $\{0,1\}$? I mean in the problem, they just state it, but I am not sure if it is by definition, by choice or are they deducing it form the info of the problem. I might as well consider for instance , in your example $L_5(\omega)\in \mathscr M_1(\{0,0.5,1\})$, the borel sigma algebra de power set of $\{0,0.5,1\}$, and $L_5(\omega,B)$ would now make sense for all of the elements of this sigma algebra....

Comment: ...Or I could consider $L_5(\omega)\in \mathscr M_1(A)$ with  $A $ any superset of  $\{0,1\}$ What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Secondly, why do you call$L_n= \text{Ber}(\tfrac{k}{n}) $. I mean the $X_n$ are of course Bernoulli random variables, but your notation seems to imply that $L_n$ is also a Bernoulli random variable- A Bernoulli r.v, according to my definition, is a random variable wich takes only to values 0 and 1. Moreover, can any Bernoulli be written with delta's?

Comment: @some_math_guy You are correct that each $L_n(\omega)$ can also be a probability measure on any suitable set containing both $0$ and $1$. It can be regarded as a measure on $\{0,0.5,1\}$, on $[0,1]$, on $\mathbb{R}$, or on whichever set you like as soon as it is a superset of $\{0,1\}$. So, I would say that the choice $\{0,1\}$ is a mere convenience.

Comment: Secondly, I am using the symbol $\text{Ber}(p)$ to denote the *Bernoulli distribution* with parameter $p$, not a Bernoulli random variable. I know that some authors exploit the notation and use sloppy expressions like "$X=\text{Ber}(p)$" to refer to a Bernoulli random variable, but I am not a fan of such convention, because there must be a clear distinction between random variables (measurable functions taking values in some state space $\mathcal{S}$) and distributions (probability measures on $\mathcal{S}$). When I'm writing $\text{Ber}(p)$, I'm exclusively referring to a distribution.